# How to search records while ignoring the special characters in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have a table in Postgres that has records like

| ID | Address |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 862 N Longbranch Road Voorhees, NJ 08043 |
| 2 | 7300 Overlook, Ave Moncks Corner, SC 29461 |
| 3 | 76 SW Green Lake, Street Sterling, VA 20164 |
| 4 | 597 Wintergreen St Erlanger, KY 41018 |

So for searching a specific address my query is simple

```
select * from profile where address ilike '7300 Overlook, Ave Moncks Corner, SC%'
```

This is returning record 2

What I want is

```
select * from profile where address ilike '7300 Overlook Ave Moncks Corner SC%'
```

(Please note that commas are missing in second query)

Even if the string inside ilike doesn't contain **comma** **,** result 2 should be returned.

Comment: You could remove all commas from the column value:  `where replace(address, ',', '') ilike ...`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name unfortunately that's not an option. There are cases where I need the address with comma(s)

Comment: The address will be return with the commas, only the comparison is done without.

Comment: As `like` should be `=` in that case the horse's suggestion is fine. You could also do `... like ,,` where you use a `%` wildcard instead of space.

Comment: You could try with the [full text search capability](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch-intro.html) also.  `SELECT * FROM profile where address @@ '7300 Overlook Ave Moncks Corner SC';` You should create an index on the address field though.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name post it as an answer so that I can accept it